# Windows XP Installation from USB

Tags: windows-xp, usb, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing Windows XP through Pen Drive](https://superuser.com/questions/63995/installing-windows-xp-through-pen-drive)

Is there any easiest way to make windows xp installation from USB ? Looking through google doesnt gives me anything. Any clues?

Comment: duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/63995/installing-windows-xp-through-pen-drive

Answer (score 3):

[How to install Windows XP using a USB flash drive](http://www.eeeguides.com/2007/11/installing-windows-xp-from-usb-thumb.html)

Answer (score 1):

Searched for "*install xp from usb*"

- http://www.vandomburg.net/installing-windows-xp-from-usb/
- http://www.boot-land.net/forums/?showtopic=4900