# How do I install Windows XP from a USB pen drive?

Tags: windows-xp, usb, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing Windows XP through Pen Drive](https://superuser.com/questions/63995/installing-windows-xp-through-pen-drive)

Is possible to install Windows XP from a USB [pen drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ka9ee.jpg)? I found many articles after searching Google, but they all talk about different approaches to do the task.

Since I didn't install XP from a pen drive before, I don't know which of those approaches are right or not.

If you've ever installed Windows XP from a USB drive, how did you do it? I'm looking for a technique that really worked for you, not something that you've read and haven't tried before.

Comment: duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/63995/installing-windows-xp-through-pen-drive

Answer (score 1):

While not a direct answer to your question, I used [this wiki](http://wiki.eeeuser.com/windowsxpusb) article when I needed to load my Eee (no CD Drive) with XP from an USB drive. Some tools and techniques there are definitely not limited to just netbooks though. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to an easy way to do this for Windows 7 and Vista that they claim works for XP as well - [How To Create Bootable Windows 7, Vista, or XP USB Flash/Pen Drive Quickly](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-create-bootable-windows-7-vista-or-xp-usb-flashpen-drive-with-a-single-click-must-try/).

I have used it for Win 7 but haven't tried it for XP.

There is also this question at SuperUser [Windows XP Installation from USB](https://superuser.com/questions/27414/windows-xp-installation-from-usb).