# Making pendrive bootable for Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, usb-flash-drive, windows-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing Windows XP from USB pen drive](https://superuser.com/questions/63995/installing-windows-xp-from-usb-pen-drive)

I have to make pen-drive bootable for my Windows XP ISO file. I'm Using Windows 7 ultimate.
I saw many links on net whose couldn't get anyone to work. I prefer CMD,as I have earlier done it for Windows 7.

**I simply need to install Windows XP from Pendrive.**

Comment: can your winxp machine boot from a pen drive? Some mobo can not recognize a bootable pen drive whether it is xp or linux based. I would make sure I can boot a linux based image first... using unebootin that Eye of Hells mentions below.

Comment: "I saw many links on net whose couldn't get anyone to work." - So what programs have you tried so far? Also, see [Installing Windows XP from USB pen drive](http://superuser.com/questions/63995/installing-windows-xp-from-usb-pen-drive), [Windows XP Installation from USB](http://superuser.com/questions/27414/windows-xp-installation-from-usb), [How do I install Windows XP from a USB pen drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/74311/how-do-i-install-windows-xp-from-a-usb-pen-drive) etc.

Answer (score 3):

**Rufus** is a small utility that helps format and create bootable USB flash drives.
Oh, and Rufus is fast. For instance it's about twice as fast as UNetbootin, Universal USB Installer or Windows 7 USB download tool, on the creation of a Windows 7 USB installation drive from an ISO.

http://rufus.akeo.ie/

It may help you achieve what u wish to accomplish

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit tricky. Try one of the following tools (one of them worked for me for different OS'es. Unfortunately, it's different one each time depending on host OS, OS i want to place on USB stick and stars disposition):

- [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)
- [Win32DiskImager](https://launchpad.net/win32-image-writer)
- [RPPrepUSB](http://www.rmprepusb.com/)